# joomla article versioning - show version

Tags: joomla, versioning, frontend

Since version 3.2 Joomla has versioning system for content. It can be enabled for articles, but I couldn't find any module or plugin to show article version on frontend and to select previous versions by frontend user. Does anybody know?

Comment: Do you mean like in a mediawiki/ That a normal non logged in user or someone without edit privleges could see the history? That doesn't exist in the core afaik but it would certainly be something you could implement with a plugin.  It would be kind of a neat thing to be able to enable.  People with edit rights can see the versions when they are editing. You'd really just want to pull up a read only version of the history from how i understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning in Joomla is a relatively new feature, and it's not greatly documented. If you're in an article view, then do print_r($this) (in the article view in the template), and you will see all the variables that the article has.

I think $article->version will do (you will need to place this in the article view in the template).

A less elegant solution would be to query the #__content table in the place where you want to show the version number:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT version FROM #__content WHERE id='".$id."'";
$version = $db->loadResult();
```